# How can I move sprite for a second every 2 seconds forever till its destroyed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skaction

I have an array of x positions and would like to move a sprite from it's current position to next xPosition to the right (moving the sprite every 2 seconds for a duration of a second) only if the position is free, else I would like to move the sprite in the opposite direction (left) if the position is free. I would like this to repeat forever till the sprite is destroyed. I am not too sure how to go about this. Below is what I've been able to do:

```
        for i in 1..<xPositions.count   {

            let delayAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)

            if freePositions.contains(xPositions[indexOfCurrentSpritePosition! + i])   {
                let spriteSpriteToRight = SKAction.moveToX(CGFloat(xPositions[indexOfCurrentSpritePosition! + i]), duration: 1.0)
                let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveSpriteToRight, delayAction])

                sprite.runAction(sequence)
            }

            else if !freePositions.contains(xPositions[indexOfCurrentSpritePosition! + i])  {
                let moveSpriteToLeft = SKAction.moveToX(CGFloat(xPositions[indexOfCurrentSpritePosition! - i]), duration: 1.0)
                let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveSpriteToLeft, delayAction])

                sprite.runAction(sequence)
            }

        }
```

Comment: What needs to happen before a sprite is destroyed? Can you provide examples of x positions (do they alternate to the left and right)?

Comment: I am not behind my laptop but I have an array of xPositions, 8 positions along the width of the screen(all of them have the same y position), Some of the positions are already occupied. The Sprite moves one position at a time to the right (every 2 seconds for a duration of a second) till it meets a filled position, then changes direction to the left, then back to right and so on. The Sprite has a body so I have set a condition in didBeginContact to destroy the Sprite on collision with another object, I guess I'll have to stop all actions on the Sprite first before I destroy it.

Comment: @0x141E I am still trying to get it to work

Comment: How do the positions become filled? Are they filled by the objects that causes the sprite to be destroyed? I think I can help you once I have a better understanding what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @0x141E okay. I create objects randomly at xPositions to fill these positions and add them to a filledPositions array. These objects that fill the positions are just obstructions to the sprite to limit it's movement. They can't destroy the sprite. There is another object that doesn't fill the xPositions that is suppose to destroy the moving sprite on contact. From the code in the post, I check to see if a position is free (in freePostitions) before moving the sprite because the xPostions array is a sum of the filledPositions and freePositions.

Comment: Also I forgot that the sprite's x position needs to be added appended to filledPositions when the sprite changes position and it's former position should be removed from the filledPositions and appended to freePositions. I hope this gives a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish